# Showing that the 2 norm of a matrix is at most 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Suppose that $A$ is an invertible matrix whose eigenvalues are at most 1. Can it be shown that $\|A\|_2 \le 1$?

I know that $A = P \Lambda P^{-1}$ which means that $\|A\|_2 \le \|P\|_2 \|\Lambda\|_2 \|P^{-1}\|_2$.

I also know that $\|\Lambda\|_2 $ is the maximum of the absolute value of the diagonal entries (which is 1).

If $A$ is symmetric, I know that $P$ is an orthonormal matrix and so the inequality holds. What about for the general case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. $\left\|\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}\right\|_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}>1$. More generally, $\left\|\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&1}\right\|_2\ge\left\|\pmatrix{t\\ 1}\right\|_2\to+\infty$ when $t\to+\infty$.

Comment: What is the eigendecomposition of that matrix? It seems like the eigenvectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: @secondrate In this example, the matrix hasn't a full eigenbasis. But that's unimportant.